# remove stopword from a String in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, stop-words

I am having trouble creating code which removes stop words from a string. Here is my code:

```
String Review="The portfolio is fine except for the fact that the last movement of sonata #6 is missing. What should one expect?";

string[] arrStopword = new string[] {"a", "i", "it", "am", "at", "on", "in", "to", "too", "very","of", "from", "here", "even", "the", "but", "and", "is","my","them", "then", "this", "that", "than", "though", "so", "are"};
StringBuilder sbReview = new StringBuilder(Review);
foreach (string word in arrStopword){
sbReview.Replace(word, "");}
Label1.Text = sbReview.ToString();
```

when running `Label1.Text = "The portfolo s fne except for fct tht lst movement st #6 s mssng. Wht should e expect? "`

I expect it must return `"portofolio fine except for  fact last movement sonata #6 is missing. what should one expect?"`

Anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use " a ", " I ", etc to make sure the program only removes those words if they're used as a word (so with spaces around them). Just replace them with a space to keep the formatting as it is.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are comparing sub strings, not words. You need to split the original text, remove the items and then join it again.

try this

```
List<string> words = Review.Split(" ").ToList();
foreach(string stopWord in arrStopWord)
    words.Remove(stopWord);
string result = String.Join(" ", words);
```

The only issue that I can see with this is that it doesnt handle punctiation that well, but you get the general idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ to solve this problem. You first need to convert your `string`,  using `Split` function, into `list` of `string` separated by `" "`(space), then use `Except` to get the words which your result will contain and then can apply `string.Join`

```
var newString = string.Join(" ", Review.Split(' ').Except(arrStopword));
```

Comment: That's a spicy meatball. Wouldn't have thought of "Except".

Comment: Lovely, elegant solution. Enhance by ignoring case using the Except overload e.g. .Except(arrStopword, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)

Answer (score 0):

Or You can use [dotnet-stop-words package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-stop-words/).
And simply call the `RemoveStopWords` method

```cs
(yourString).RemoveStopWords("en");
```